# Why the weird lag in Screen Sharing app when using the LG Ultrafine 5K monitor?

Tags: display, screen-sharing

Hardware:

Late 2016 MacBook Pro w/ TouchBar
LG Ultrafine 5K display

Setup:

Screen Sharing app connected to remote instance in the cloud

Problem:

Very slow response to keystrokes.  There is no problem in other applications.   The problem goes away if I disconnect the external display.  The problem does not go away if I switch from WiFi to a hardwired Ethernet connection.  I had thought this might be the monitor's shielding problem interfering with WiFi but no, it happens without WiFi.  Truly perplexing!

Comment: Presuming you've tried `View` > `Adaptive Quality` in the Screen Sharing app?

Comment: I hadn't but I see it's checked anyway.  Should I try "Full Quality"?

Comment: Go for it - should increase lag though not reduce it haha. Equally have you tried 3rd-party stuff with much more customisability regarding compression, exact colour etc (I'm thinking of VNCViewer Free which I use all the time for speedy Linux screen sharing).

Comment: Ha! VNCViewer fixes it!  What on earth could make Screen Sharing not play nicely with an external monitor?

Comment: It's Apple's homespun (read terrible) version of VNC which has multiple seemingly inexplicable issues. I ditched the ScreenSharing app for VNCViewer years ago. Only thing you might miss is forwarding clipboard contents into a session (or retrieving them seamlessly) and of course drag and drop with files.

Comment: VNCViewer is copying the clipboard back and forth between MacOS and Linux just fine, much better than Screen Sharing which I could only get to go from Linux to MacOS.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, do please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's implementation of VNC ScreenSharing often falls short, with significant lag regardless of whether `Adaptive Quality` is selected or not. A more robust 3rd-party solution like (the free) [VNCViewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) will provide you with fine-grained compression control, allowing workable VNC sessions over the tightest of bandwidth (e.g. through a shell tunnel to a remote server with really low upload speeds).